# Is it possible to have alternative login in azure b2c?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

we are planning to use azure ad b2c to authenticate our customers.

At the moment our customers can either use their email + password OR their customer number + password to login to our apps.

Is this possible in azure ad b2c?

regards
Stefan

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use username instead of email to login in AD B2C.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [a built-in flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows), then the sign-in name can be set to either an e-mail address *or* a user name.

If you use [a custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started?tabs=applications), then both can be supported at the same time.

An example of a custom policy that supports both can be found at [Sign In and Sign Up with Username or Email](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-or-email).

Comment: The sample is for one or the other decided at signup. Is there a sample for having both stored but allowing one to enter either at sign-in?